# Create public property List<childUc> in ParentUc C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

-I create a user control name childUc
-And I create another user control name ParentUc

I create a public property List in ParentUc

```
private List<childUc> _child = new List<childUc>();

public List<childUc> MyChild
{
get {return _child;}
set 
{_child = value;}
}
```

-when I rebuilt (F6) and add ParentUc from Toolbox
-when I try to add MyChild from Properties Panelbox I've always got an Error

How to fix this?
How can I add List property to ParentUc properties?

Thank

Comment: What error do you get? Are you intending that this `List<childUc>` are actual controls in the parent control? Why not use the parents `.Controls` property for this instead of using your own? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: When I added (drag ucParent User Control from Toolbox) to the form to use I've 2 errors
the last one is

Comment: I try to use childUc as an item of the parentUc, look like what ListView provided we can add and remove ListviewItem from the Listview properties panel.